# Results from multiple tables with same column names by same id using ASP from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I am needing some help writing in ASP getting data from SQL.

I have 3 tables - PC, Monitor & Monitor2. The Monitor2 table is an exact clone of the Monitor table, data included. (dont ask me why, done before my time here)

Columns used from PC table
PC_ID, Name (plus a few others but not relevant here)

Columns in Monitor & Monitor2 tables
Monitor_ID, Name, Size, PC_ID, Make, mNotes

Basically i need to pull results to populate a table that shows which PC.Name  has which Monitor.Name,  Monitor2.Name,  and other attributes.

eg.

```
|  PC Name  |  Monitor 1  |  Monitor 2  |  Other 1 |  Other 2 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|   PC254   |    M133     |     M176    |    27    |   27     |
```

this is what i have so far

```
sqlq = "SELECT PC.PC_ID, PC.PC_Name, PC.CPU, PC.RAM, PC.Make, PC.Model, PC.Date, Monitor2.Name as mon_name2, Monitor2.Size as mon_size2, Monitor.Name as mon_name, Monitor.Size as mon_size FROM Monitor right JOIN PC ON Monitor.PC_ID = PC.PC_ID FROM Monitor2 right JOIN PC ON Monitor2.PC_ID = PC.PC_ID
set rs = conn.execute(sqlq)
if rs.eof or rs.bof then
response.write("No Records Found")
else
'count how many records have been returned
count=0
rs.movefirst
pcname=""
do while not rs.eof
if pcname <> rs("PC_Name") then
count=count+1
end if
pcname=rs("PC_Name")
rs.movenext
loop

Response.write("<font size='2'>No. of records returned:" & count & " </font>")
rs.movefirst
pcname=""
%>
<%if not PrintF then %>
```

Then getting the ouput like

```
<%do while not rs.eof
if pcname <> rs("PC_Name") then
%>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 96px"><a href="PCView.asp?PC=<%=rs("PC_ID")%>"><font size="1"><%=rs("PC_Name")%></font></a></td>
    <td><a href="PCView.asp?PC=<%=rs("PC_ID")%>"><font size="1"><%=rs("Name")%></font></a></td>

    <td style="width: 99px"><font size="1"><%=rs("mon_name")%></font></td>
    <td style="width: 99px"><font size="1"><%=rs("mon_name2")%></font></td>
    <td><font size="1"><%=rs("mon_size")%></font></td>
    <td><font size="1"><%=rs("mon_size2")%></font></td>

</tr>
<%
end if
pcname=rs("PC_Name")
rs.movenext
loop%>
```

But as of yet i cannot get around the

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14' 

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. 

/PCs/SearchResult.asp, line 31
```

If it's not that then i get something like 
"The multi-part identifier "Monitor2.Name" could not be bound."
or some other Incorrect syntax error.

Cheers for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

`FROM Monitor right JOIN PC ON Monitor.PC_ID = PC.PC_ID FROM Monitor2`

Take out the second `FROM` .. which is  `FROM Monitor2`

This leaves you with

```
SELECT  PC.PC_ID,
        PC.PC_Name,
        PC.CPU,
        PC.RAM,
        PC.Make,
        PC.Model,
        PC.Date,
        Monitor2.Name AS mon_name2,
        Monitor2.Size AS mon_size2,
        Monitor.Name AS mon_name,
        Monitor.Size AS mon_size
FROM    Monitor
        RIGHT JOIN PC ON Monitor.PC_ID = PC.PC_ID
        RIGHT JOIN PC ON Monitor2.PC_ID = PC.PC_ID
```

which doesn't make sense and is also incorrect.  I think you're trying to do something like this instead

```
SELECT  PC.PC_ID,
        PC.PC_Name,
        PC.CPU,
        PC.RAM,
        PC.Make,
        PC.Model,
        PC.Date,
        Monitor2.Name AS mon_name2,
        Monitor2.Size AS mon_size2,
        Monitor.Name AS mon_name,
        Monitor.Size AS mon_size
FROM    PC
        LEFT JOIN Monitor ON Monitor.PC_ID = PC.PC_ID
        LEFT JOIN Monitor2 ON Monitor2.PC_ID = PC.PC_ID
```

if you have multiple records in Monitor or Monitor2 for one PC_ID you will get dupes.

Comment: JamieD77 as you were really helpful, could you have a look at the othe question ive just posted...needing fresh eyes. Thx - [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313947/trying-to-write-update-back-to-sql-in-asp-incorrect-syntax-near)