# Trying to write UPDATE back to SQL in ASP - Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I'm a bit green when it comes to Classic ASP, so I apologize in advance.

I have an asp page with a form that gets filled in with details of pc equipment. this then adds it to the SQL database. Works a charm...

However, on the view page where we can then change any of the details, when I click the "save changes" button I get an error.

> Incorrect syntax near '='

Here is what I have:

```
<!-- #include file="Tauthenticate.asp" -->

<!--#include file="database.asp"-->

<%

pcname=request.form("T1")
pctype=request.form("T2")
pccpu=request.form("T3")
pcram=request.form("T4")
pcmake=request.form("T5")
pcmodel=request.form("T5b")
pcdate=request.form("T6")
graphics=request.form("T7")
notes=request.form("T8")
tag=request.form("T9")
cd_dvd=request.form("T10")


sqlq = "UPDATE PC set PC_Name='" & pcname & "', Type='" & pctype & "', CPU='" & pccpu & "', RAM='" & pcram & "', Make='" & pcmake & "', Model='" & pcmodel & "', Date='" & pcdate & "', Graphics='" & graphics & "', Notes='" & notes & "', Service_Tag='" & tag & "', CD_DVD='" & cd_dvd & "' where PC_ID=" & pcid
response.write(sqlq)
conn.execute(sqlq)
Response.Redirect("../PCs/PCView.asp?pc=" & pcid)



%>
```

After a quick test, i get this result

> UPDATE PC set PC_Name='LRW9999', Type='Desktop PC', CPU='blah blah', RAM='5555', Make='blah blah', Model='doo doo', Date='09/02/16', Graphics='blah blah', Notes='test only', Service_Tag='gyudsgysdgsgghfs', CD_DVD='9999' where PC_ID=
>
> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'
>
> Incorrect syntax near '='.
>
> /PCs/SaveChangesnew.asp, line 28

Where am I going wrong? It seems I can't see the wood for the trees and I need fresh eyes to help me.

Comment: `pcid` is empty. you never assign it

Answer (score 0):

Update your sqlquery to following:

```
sqlq = "UPDATE PC set PC_Name='" & pcname & "', Type='" & pctype & "', CPU='" & pccpu & "', RAM='" & pcram & "', Make='" & pcmake & "', Model='" & pcmodel & "', Date='" & pcdate & "', Graphics='" & graphics & "', Notes='" & notes & "', Service_Tag='" & tag & "', CD_DVD='" & cd_dvd & "' where PC_ID='" & pcid &"'"
```

Comment: How about you explain the problem?

Comment: This isn't a fix the `PC_ID` field is likely an `INT` trying to explicitly cast it to a `VARCHAR` will just cause an error. The issue is the OP is not assigning anything to `pcid` as [@jens has pointed out in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313947/trying-to-write-update-back-to-sql-in-asp-incorrect-syntax-near#comment58336761_35313947).

Comment: @RicardoPontual True, I did say it would error...thinking about it it possibly won't not sure if you pass an empty `VARCHAR` to an `INT` field what will happen off top of my head. But either way it's not the way to approach the problem just pass a value for `pcid` or check it first and not run the update if it's not present etc.